# Changing the value in a binded Angular table with [(NgModel)] affects other fields

Tags: angular

I have a table with 1 character long fields that gets generated by ***ngFor** from a 2-dimensional array, defined as:

```
<table>​
    <tr *ngFor="let row of table; index as i">
        <td *ngFor="let field of row; index as j">
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="table[i][j]" type="text" maxlength="1" contenteditable="true" />
        </td>​
    </tr>​
</table>​
```

The idea is to let the user modify the contents of `table` in a visual manner and to get straight away the modified table to process its contents.

The problem comes when modifying the value in a single field, as it affects randomly to other fields in the same line. I have recreated the problem with random values in the following link:

[**StackBlitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-repruz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by adding a "[trackBy](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)" function to your *ngFor loops.
Updated StackBlitz demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t7f9hx